# Input not changing state REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

The input doesn't change it's text. It comes pre-filled from the database. For example, if it comes with the text: `example`, if I press for example the `s` key, it console logs `examples` but in the DOM in is still `example`. Here is the `handle` code:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
```

and the input field:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  className="form-control" 
  name="note" 
  id=" note" 
  value={this.state.insurance.note} 
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

**EDIT**  (*fixed the render problem, but I don't get the data that I want when I submit the form*)
Here is the code for my form:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var state = this.state;
    axios
      .put(`${API_URL}/` + state.id + `/update`, {
        tip: state.tip,
        date_exp: state.date_exp,
        date_notif: state.date_notif,
        note: state.note
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        // window.location = "/view";
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

and my button is a simple submit button:

```
<button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imjared's answer is correct: your problem is in the `handleChange` function, where you wrongly update the state.
That function should be something like the following one:

```
handleChange = event => {
    const insurance = Object.assign({}, this.state.insurance);
    insurance[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({insurance});
  };
```

In the first line of the function, you create a deep copy of the current object `insurance` saved in the state. Then, you update the copied object, and finally update the state.

Comment: The thing is that now when I submit the form, it `console.log`es and empty object... Before it `console.log`ed and object with the fileds that i have modified...

Comment: could you please post also the code of your submit button? :)

Comment: Well, if you mean that the `console.log(response.data)` returns an empty object, that depends on the fetch that is not working correctly. By looking at your request, I do wonder: isn't by, any chance, that you should have written `state.insurance.date_exp`, `state.insurance.date_notif` instead of `state.date_exp`... ?
I mean, before you handled the change on the `insurance` object, but in that request it seems that you do not have any `insurance` object in the state

Comment: Yeah, you're right, so sorry for the dumb question... That was it... Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks, you too! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're changing `this.state.note` based on the `name` property of your input so it makes sense that `this.state.insurance.note` wouldn't see any updates.

If you try console.logging `this.state` above your `<input>`, I bet you'll see what you're after.